# Bash running time optimization

Tags: bash, optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem and to find the most efficient way of performing the following commands:

`whois -> sed -> while (exit while) ->perform action`

while loop currently look like

```
while [x eq smth]; do
x=$((x+1))
done

some action
```

Maybe it is more efficient to have while true with an if inside (if clause the same as for while). Also, what is the best case using bash to evaluate the time required for every single step?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that this is in anyway a bottleneck for your task?

Comment: If you're that concerned about efficiency in a shell script, perhaps you should be writing this in C or C++ or something else rather than an interpreted scripting language.

Comment: The `sed` (or any other child process) is probably your main overhead, rewriting the loop is unlikely to make a significant difference.  Consider using shell expansion instead of `sed`, or write the whole lot in `awk`, or maybe even `perl` if you have complex code.

Comment: @tvalberg the script includes curl/etc, however will consider option regarding c/c++.

In such a case, what would be the most efficient programming language that would contain curl/find/substr?

Answer (score 2):

The by far biggest performance penalty and most common performance problem in Bash is unnecessary forking.

```
while [[ something ]]
do
    var+=$(echo "$expression" | awk '{print $1}')
done
```

will be thousands of times slower than

```
while [[ something ]]
do
    var+=${expression%% *}
done
```

Since the former will cause two forks per iteration, while the latter causes none.

Things that cause forks include but are not limited to `pipe | lines`, `$(command expansion)`, `<(process substitution)`, `(explicit subshells)`, and using any command not listed in `help` (which `type somecmd` will identify as 'builtin' or 'shell keyword').

Comment: So what would you suggest for such script evaluation, using simple date ?

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you could remove `$(`, this creates a subshell and is sure
to slow the task down somewhat

```
while [ x -eq smth ]
do
  (( x++ ))
done
```

Comment: $((expr)) is unrelated to $(expr) and does not cause a subshell.